Как мне вывести значение 'а' из цикла
Я хочу сделать код высчитывающий проценты. Но мне не удаётся вернуть изменённое значение из цикла
package ILBC;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Percents {
    public static double Percentage (double Money, double YearPercent, double Years) {
        double a = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i == Years; i++) {
            a += (Money * (YearPercent / 100));
        }
        return a;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner cs = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Сумма");
        double Money = cs.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Время (сколько лет)");
        double Years = cs.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Годовой процент");
        double YearPercent = cs.nextDouble();
        cs.close();

        System.out.println(Percentage(Money, YearPercent, Years));
    }
}


вижу слово Percentage но не вижу почему оно написано без указания класса (и IDE должна была явно об этом рассказать)

@АлексейШиманский Это статический метод, который вызывается из main. Если класс не указан, то IDE высвечивает его курсивом, имея ввиду текущий класс.

@RomanC просто был текст невнятно оформлен и подумал, что это отдельный класс был.

@АлексейШиманский Для доступа к статическим переменным или методам класса нужно указывать префикс класса, но в текущем классе это не обязательно, хотя желательно. Если бы это был отдельный класс, то для вызова конструктора класса используется оператор new. По поводу именования классов, надо придерживаться конвенций наименований Java. То есть переменные и методы именуются в камель-стиле, а классы пишутся с заглавной буквы.

@RomanC не понял к чему вы это написали. Ещё и так много и про какой-то конвеншн..... Для доступа к статическому методу класса не нужны никакие new и должно было быть Percents.Percentage.  Ещё раз повторю: изначально  текст ТС был невнятно оформлен и казалось, что метод main находится в одном классе, а метод Percentage в классе Percents. После того, как привели код в вопросе в адекватное состояние - видно, что методы находятся в одном и том же классе и, конечно, мой первый комментарий не актуален в связи из-за конкретно этого момента

@АлексейШиманский К чему я это написал, про конвеншн можно прочитать тут. В предыдущем комментарии я рассказал почему был опущен префикс класса и почему его надо ставить. Если комментарий не актуален, то его надо удалять. С большой буквы пишутся не названия методов, а названия классов. Ошибка может быть в том, что ОП пытался создать объект класса, и это нужно было подтвердить, что это не так. Если подтверждения не было, то ответов больше он не получит, несмотря на то что проблема уже решена.

@RomanC а зачем вы МНЕ пишете про конвеншн? Это вы автору топика пишите

@АлексейШиманский Потому, что "подумал, что это отдельный класс был". Если это отдельный класс, а не метод то должны быть разъяснения. Зачем тогда писать свой комментарий. Это стэк оверфлоу и здесь комментарии пишутся со смыслом. Мой комментарий можешь считать как репли.

Во-первых, в коде есть опечатка в условии цикла i == Years, из-за которой цикл не выполняет ни одной итерации, и соответственно метод всегда возвращает значение 0.
Во-вторых, даже если исправить эту опечатку, чтобы проверялось условие i < Years, вычисления останутся неправильными.
Например, при вводе дробных значений Years всегда будет начисляться процент за полный год, когда реально останется меньше года.
В-третьих, в представленном коде не вычисляется сложный процент, т.е. не происходит капитализация процентов (они не прибавляются к основной сумме), поэтому цикл для таких вычислений вообще не нужен, достаточно было бы вернуть результат простого умножения:  Money * YearPercent * Years / 100.
Для вычисления сложного процента с учётом капитализации процентов в конце каждой итерации следовало бы прибавить к Money накопленный процент.
В-четвертых, для финансовых вычислений используется неподходящий тип данных с  плавающей точкой, из-за чего могут возникнуть ошибки округления.
Вариант исправленного кода:
public static double totalRevenue(double amount, double interestRate, double years) {
    double total = 0;
    interestRate /= 100;
    
    while (years > 0) {
        double revenue = Math.round(amount * interestRate * Math.min(1, years) * 100) / 100d;
        total  = Math.round(100 * (total  + revenue)) / 100d;
        amount = Math.round(100 * (amount + revenue)) / 100d;
        years -= 1;
    }
    return total;
}

